# OrientDB : How do I implement pagination?

Tags: orientdb

I have gone through [this documentation about pagination](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/Pagination.html).

It says `Skip-Limit` is the slower way because `OrientDB` repeats the query and just skips the first `X` records from the result. I want to skip `100000` records and select the next `20`.

Will this query die? Is there any other way I can achieve this, but without using `RID-LIMIT`?

Comment: Any reason for not using RID Limit? It does exactly what you want, you just need to learn how to use it.

Comment: I want to sort by name (instead of rid) and then paginate